# Err Response Headers Multiple Location

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have made a php file and save it in root as brothersofusa.php. And in the file I type only:

```
<?php 
header("Location: ". "http://www.google.com");
?>
```

When I execute the page, it returns an error, a blank page with error **ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_LOCATION**.

Please help me out of here. What do I do ?

Comment: This alone doesn't give you this error. `:)` Post the full code?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `exit();` after the redirect:

```
    header("Location: ". "http://www.google.com");
    exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Header HAS to be the first thing to be on a page, for example you cannot `echo` something before that.

Make sure it is the first line.